# Send Image and Text both using ACTION_SEND or ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE

Tags: android, android-intent, sharing, posting

**-** We have tried to post **image** and **text** using the below code:

```
final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
shareIntent.setType("image/png");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/UserImages/"+ ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId() + ".png"));
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Hello test");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Share"));
```

**-** We have also tried using  `shareIntent.setType("*/*")`, but still no luck.

**-** When we are trying to post this on `email`, only text is appearing in it, and when we tried posting it on `whatsapp` then only the image was visible.

**-** We are unable to post both together, can anyone suggest the proper way of doing it.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Now your code gonna work due the new updates to whatsapp, before this didn't accept this kind of intent (ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE) because it accepts only one file at a time.