# Is It possible to send an image and a text file, both using a single Intent in android?

Tags: android, image, android-intent, text

The question is (might be a repeated one), but I could not find a proper answer to it, so asking here again.
In my application, I need to share both an image and a text file using a single intent.
I read a few answers, like:
[ACTION_SEND sending both an Image and Text in the same Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931611/action-send-sending-both-an-image-and-text-in-the-same-intent),
[Send Image and Text both using ACTION_SEND or ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357872/send-image-and-text-both-using-action-send-or-action-send-multiple)
and also [Problems sharing combined text and image with SHARE INTENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296605/problems-sharing-combined-text-and-image-with-share-intent-on-twitter)

and tried to implement the given solutions in my application, but none of them worked for me.

The code I've implemented so far is as below :

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "I found movie "+movieTitle+" on Movies Tracker!");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "my text");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
        share.setType("image/*");
        share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share via"));
```

So now my question is: is there any way to share both an image and a text file with single intent?
If it's possible, then please help regarding this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/image.jpg");
sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body text of the new
status");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image
using"));

Comment: How exactly you need to send image i.e from drawable folder or from sdcard ?